# php mysql results in printed table not matching what I get in mysql admin when I run the same query

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my problem.  I run a query in mysqladmin and the results are as expected.  When I run the query in php and print to a table on the web server I get the same number of columns, but the data in the rows after the header are mixed up.  Am I doing something wrong with the way I am printing the data in PHP?  This code works for a different query so I'm stumped.

Here is my code if you can help me figure out why my mysqladmin results are different from what is printed to the screen when I call this php file.

Here is what is not displaying correctly.  Entry_id is a primary key and should always be filled in.
[error http://www.sweatmansc.com/fo_claims/images/weberrorreport.PNG](http://www.sweatmansc.com/fo_claims/images/weberrorreport.PNG)
Here is the same query in mysqladmin
[good http://www.sweatmansc.com/fo_claims/images/mysqladminresults.PNG](http://www.sweatmansc.com/fo_claims/images/mysqladminresults.PNG)

```
    $select = "(SELECT `tbl_entry`.`entry_id`,`tbl_entry_item`.`entry_item_id`,
    CASE
        WHEN `tbl_entry`.`in_out_type` = 'I' THEN 'Inbound'
        WHEN `tbl_entry`.`in_out_type` = 'O' THEN 'Shipped Out'
        ELSE ''
    END AS 'Status',
    `tbl_customer`.`customer_name`,
    `tbl_serv_prov`.`name` AS 'Carrier_name',
    `tbl_origin_dest`.`name` AS 'Origin',
    destination.`name` AS 'Destination',
    `tbl_project`.`project_name`,
    `tbl_component`.`component_name`,
    CASE 
        WHEN `tbl_entry`.`truck_arrive` < '1999-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '0'
        ELSE `tbl_entry`.`truck_arrive`
    END AS 'truck_arrive',

    CASE 
        WHEN `tbl_entry`.`offload_begin` < '1999-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '0'
        ELSE `tbl_entry`.`offload_begin`
    END AS 'offload_begin',
    CASE 
        WHEN `tbl_entry`.`offload_end` < '1999-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '0'
        ELSE `tbl_entry`.`offload_end`
    END AS 'offload_end',
    CASE 
        WHEN `tbl_entry`.`truck_left_site` < '1999-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '0'
        ELSE `tbl_entry`.`truck_left_site`
    END AS 'truck_left_site',
    `tbl_entry`.`pro_number`,
    `tbl_entry`.`checklist`,
    `tbl_entry`.`truck_rail_barge`,`tbl_entry`.`bol`,
    `tbl_entry`.`log_mode`,`tbl_entry_item`.`damage`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`serial_number`,`tbl_entry_item`.`dmg_desc`,
    ds.`status_name` AS 'Damage_Type',`tbl_entry_item`.`fix_before_ship`,
    fs.`status_name` AS 'Fix_status',`tbl_entry_item`.`mpp_defect`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`incident`,`tbl_entry_item`.`defect_avoided`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`damage_source`,`tbl_entry_item`.`defect`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`defect_comments`,`tbl_entry_item`.`incident_escalation`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`incident_injury`,`tbl_entry_item`.`incident_report_link`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`in_out_type`,`tbl_entry_item`.`incident_esc_sent`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`defect_comment`,`tbl_entry_item`.`mpp_reason`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`claim_check`,`tbl_entry_item`.`set_number`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`customer_tag`,`tbl_entry_item`.`outbound_entry_id`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`outbound_entry_item_id`,

    out_tbl_entry.`entry_id`,out_tbl_entry_item.`entry_item_id`,
    CASE
        WHEN out_tbl_entry.`in_out_type` = 'I' THEN 'Inbound'
        WHEN out_tbl_entry.`in_out_type` = 'O' THEN 'Shipped Out'
        ELSE ''
    END AS 'Out_Status',
    '' AS 'CUSTOMER_Outbound',
    out_tbl_serv_prov.`name` AS 'Outbound_Carrier_name',
    out_tbl_origin_dest.`name` AS 'Origin_out',
    out_destination.`name` AS 'Destination_out',
    '' AS 'PROJECT_Outbound',
    out_tbl_component.`component_name`,
    CASE 
        WHEN out_tbl_entry.`truck_arrive` < '1999-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '0'
        ELSE out_tbl_entry.`truck_arrive`
    END AS 'out_truck_arrive',

    CASE 
        WHEN out_tbl_entry.`offload_begin` < '1999-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '0'
        ELSE out_tbl_entry.`offload_begin`
    END AS 'load_begin',
    CASE 
        WHEN out_tbl_entry.`offload_end` < '1999-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '0'
        ELSE out_tbl_entry.`offload_end`
    END AS 'load_end',
    CASE 
        WHEN out_tbl_entry.`truck_left_site` < '1999-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '0'
        ELSE out_tbl_entry.`truck_left_site`
    END AS 'truck_left_site',
    out_tbl_entry.`pro_number`,
    out_tbl_entry.`checklist`,
    out_tbl_entry.`truck_rail_barge`,
    out_tbl_entry.`bol`,
    out_tbl_entry.`log_mode`,
    out_tbl_entry_item.`damage`,
    out_tbl_entry_item.`serial_number`,
    out_tbl_entry_item.`dmg_desc`,
    out_ds.`status_name` AS 'Damage_Type',out_tbl_entry_item.`fix_before_ship`,
    out_fs.`status_name` AS 'Fix_status',out_tbl_entry_item.`mpp_defect`,
    out_tbl_entry_item.`incident`,out_tbl_entry_item.`defect_avoided`,
    out_tbl_entry_item.`damage_source`,out_tbl_entry_item.`defect`,
    out_tbl_entry_item.`defect_comments`,out_tbl_entry_item.`incident_escalation`,
    out_tbl_entry_item.`incident_injury`,out_tbl_entry_item.`incident_report_link`,
    out_tbl_entry_item.`in_out_type`,out_tbl_entry_item.`incident_esc_sent`,
    out_tbl_entry_item.`defect_comment`,out_tbl_entry_item.`mpp_reason`,
    out_tbl_entry_item.`claim_check`,out_tbl_entry_item.`set_number`,
    out_tbl_entry_item.`customer_tag`,
    out_tbl_entry_item.`outbound_entry_id` AS 'next_entry_link',
    out_tbl_entry_item.`outbound_entry_item_id` AS 'next_entry_id_link'

    FROM tbl_entry
        LEFT JOIN tbl_entry_item ON `tbl_entry`.`entry_id`=`tbl_entry_item`.`entry_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_customer ON `tbl_entry`.`customer_id`=`tbl_customer`.`customer_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_serv_prov ON `tbl_entry`.`serv_prov_id`=`tbl_serv_prov`.`serv_prov_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_origin_dest ON `tbl_entry`.`location`=`tbl_origin_dest`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_origin_dest destination ON `tbl_entry`.`dest`= destination.`id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_project ON `tbl_entry`.`project_id`=`tbl_project`.`project_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_component ON `tbl_entry_item`.`component_id`=`tbl_component`.`component_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_status ds ON `tbl_entry_item`.`dmg_type`= ds.`status_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_status fs ON `tbl_entry_item`.`fix_status`= fs.`status_id` 

        LEFT JOIN tbl_entry_item out_tbl_entry_item ON `tbl_entry_item`.`outbound_entry_item_id`=out_tbl_entry_item.`entry_item_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_entry out_tbl_entry ON out_tbl_entry_item.`entry_id`= out_tbl_entry.`entry_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_serv_prov out_tbl_serv_prov ON out_tbl_entry.`serv_prov_id`=out_tbl_serv_prov.`serv_prov_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_origin_dest out_tbl_origin_dest ON out_tbl_entry.`location`=out_tbl_origin_dest.`id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_origin_dest out_destination ON out_tbl_entry.`dest`= out_destination.`id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_component out_tbl_component ON out_tbl_entry_item.`component_id`=out_tbl_component.`component_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_status out_ds ON out_tbl_entry_item.`dmg_type`= ds.`status_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_status out_fs ON out_tbl_entry_item.`fix_status`= fs.`status_id`                          
    WHERE   `tbl_entry`.`in_out_type` = 'I' )
UNION
(SELECT 'No Inbound Record tied to this Outbound Record',
    'See Column to right for Outbound Record','','','','',
    '','','','','',
    '','','','','',
    '','','','','',
    '','','','','',
    '','','','','',
    '','','','','',
    '','','','','','',
    `tbl_entry`.`entry_id`,`tbl_entry_item`.`entry_item_id`,
    CASE
        WHEN `tbl_entry`.`in_out_type` = 'I' THEN 'Inbound'
        WHEN `tbl_entry`.`in_out_type` = 'O' THEN 'Outbound'
        ELSE ''
    END AS 'Status',
    `tbl_customer`.`customer_name`,
    `tbl_serv_prov`.`name` AS 'Carrier_name',
    `tbl_origin_dest`.`name` AS 'Origin',
    destination.`name` AS 'Destination',
    `tbl_project`.`project_name`,
    `tbl_component`.`component_name`,
    CASE 
        WHEN `tbl_entry`.`truck_arrive` < '1999-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '0'
        ELSE `tbl_entry`.`truck_arrive`
    END AS 'truck_arrive',

    CASE 
        WHEN `tbl_entry`.`offload_begin` < '1999-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '0'
        ELSE `tbl_entry`.`offload_begin`
    END AS 'offload_begin',
    CASE 
        WHEN `tbl_entry`.`offload_end` < '1999-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '0'
        ELSE `tbl_entry`.`offload_end`
    END AS 'offload_end',
    CASE 
        WHEN `tbl_entry`.`truck_left_site` < '1999-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '0'
        ELSE `tbl_entry`.`truck_left_site`
    END AS 'truck_left_site',
    `tbl_entry`.`pro_number`,
    `tbl_entry`.`checklist`,
    `tbl_entry`.`truck_rail_barge`,`tbl_entry`.`bol`,
    `tbl_entry`.`log_mode`,`tbl_entry_item`.`damage`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`serial_number`,`tbl_entry_item`.`dmg_desc`,
    ds.`status_name` AS 'Damage_Type',`tbl_entry_item`.`fix_before_ship`,
    fs.`status_name` AS 'Fix_status',`tbl_entry_item`.`mpp_defect`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`incident`,`tbl_entry_item`.`defect_avoided`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`damage_source`,`tbl_entry_item`.`defect`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`defect_comments`,`tbl_entry_item`.`incident_escalation`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`incident_injury`,`tbl_entry_item`.`incident_report_link`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`in_out_type`,`tbl_entry_item`.`incident_esc_sent`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`defect_comment`,`tbl_entry_item`.`mpp_reason`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`claim_check`,`tbl_entry_item`.`set_number`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`customer_tag`,`tbl_entry_item`.`outbound_entry_id`,
    `tbl_entry_item`.`outbound_entry_item_id`

    FROM tbl_entry
        LEFT JOIN tbl_entry_item ON `tbl_entry`.`entry_id`=`tbl_entry_item`.`entry_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_customer ON `tbl_entry`.`customer_id`=`tbl_customer`.`customer_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_serv_prov ON `tbl_entry`.`serv_prov_id`=`tbl_serv_prov`.`serv_prov_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_origin_dest ON `tbl_entry`.`location`=`tbl_origin_dest`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_origin_dest destination ON `tbl_entry`.`dest`= destination.`id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_project ON `tbl_entry`.`project_id`=`tbl_project`.`project_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_component ON `tbl_entry_item`.`component_id`=`tbl_component`.`component_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_status ds ON `tbl_entry_item`.`dmg_type`= ds.`status_id`
        LEFT JOIN tbl_status fs ON `tbl_entry_item`.`fix_status`= fs.`status_id` 

    WHERE   `tbl_entry`.`in_out_type` = 'O' AND `tbl_entry_item`.`entry_item_id` NOT IN  (SELECT outbound_entry_item_id
                                                                FROM  `tbl_entry_item` 
                                                                WHERE outbound_entry_item_id IS NOT NULL )
);";

$export = mysql_query ( $select ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );
$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

// datadunp
$rowIterator = 1;

//debug
echo "<table><tr>";
//header
$col = 0;
for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header = mysql_field_name( $export , $i );
    //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $rowIterator, $header);
    echo "<td>";
    echo $header;
    echo "</td>";
    $col++;
}
$rowIterator++; //end header

echo "</tr>";
//begin body
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($export)) {
   $col = 0;

    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
        //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $rowIterator, $value);
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td>";
        $col++;
    }
    $rowIterator++;
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: There are 84 columns.  When I reduce the number of columns it seems to make the query work.  Is there an issue with having so many columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
        //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $rowIterator, $value);
        echo "<td>";
        //echo $value;
        echo htmlspecialchars($value);
        echo "</td>";
        $col++;
    }
```

Maybe your query data contains some special characters which cannnot be displayed in HTML.

If htmlspecialchars() doesn't work, you may want to try htmlentities().

Comment: Tried both htmlentities and htmlspecialchars just now, but still no change.

Comment: I did two things, first changed my mysql to mysqli then I had to go back and alias the tables that were repeated.  For some reason this fixed it.